# Validaiton on Phone no for multiple countries

Tags: javascript

I have an application that has records of multiple countries' users.And I am recording the phone no. of each user.And i want to apply validation on phone no country wise format.

Thanks!

Comment: Validate how? Do you want to check the format only, or validate the actual number? Do you need to filter out premium / mobile numbers somebody could put in fraudulently? How do you want to keep up to date with changes, that can happen quite rapidly in fast-growing phone systems? And it would certainly be helpful to specify which countries you mean - there's hardly going to be a collection of validation rules for all 192 countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhoneFormat.com](http://www.phoneformat.com/) has a javascript library that will do exactly what your looking for.  You can pass it a phone number in any format, and it will return the country code, and also convert it to e164 and it can format it too.

Comment: Website seems sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

Validating the format 100% will be near impossible, you will have to make some sacrifices.

I only know about UK phone numbers, but there are countless possible valid number formats, and different ways of representing them, eg:

```
+44 2345 123 456
02345123456
1234 56 78
```

your best bet would be to validate it only contains numbers and spaces, starts with a +. it could also contain a # for extensions?

some simple regex would be:

```
/\+?[\d+](\#\d+)?/i
```